# Twitter Bootstrap popover trigger: how to set multiple triggers?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers. I can set the trigger to any one of `click | hover | focus | manual`. Is there a way to set multiple triggers? I want to use hover and focus.

Comment: Use `manual` and open the popover manually after subscribing to the events you'd like.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Also, can you please put that down as an answer so I can accept it if it helps?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is easy enough to accomplish by defining your own event handlers and showing/hiding the popover via the API:

**HTML:**

```
<input id='no-popover' type='text' />
<input id='has-popover' type='text' placeholder='hover or focus me' />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var showPopover = function () {
    $(this).popover('show');
}
, hidePopover = function () {
    $(this).popover('hide');
};

$('#has-popover').popover({
    content: 'Popover content',
    trigger: 'manual'
})
.focus(showPopover)
.blur(hidePopover)
.hover(showPopover, hidePopover);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Xqx8P/

Answer (score 11):

When initializing your popover, you may pass multiple triggers; separate them with a space.

```
   var options = {
       trigger: 'hover focus'
    }

    $('#has-popover').popover(options);
```

Answer (score 2):

Related to this question:

if anyone uses Bootstrap's popover with AngularJS (using [Angular-UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover)) and wants to define that a popover will be **activated** "on mouse enter" but **deactivated** according to one or more events, this code might be helpful:

```
app.config(function ($tooltipProvider) {
    // when the user either leaves the element or clicks on it, the tooltip/popover will go off.
    $tooltipProvider.setTriggers({
        'mouseenter': 'mouseleave click',
        'click': 'click',
        'focus': 'blur'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use multiple triggers in this way : trigger="focus; click;"

Answer (score 0):

The reference of what mentioned correctly by @Denis Ivanov

Bootstrap 3.0 (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)

> How popover is triggered - click | hover | focus | manual. You may
>   pass multiple triggers; separate them with a space. Default is 'click'

Answer (score 0):

If you use data attributes inside your `<a>` tag to configure your popover, you can simply put both values, like this:

`<a data-trigger="hover focus">`

Works for me using Bootstrap 2.