# Triggering popover on button hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, twitter-bootstrap

I've looked everywhere for a solution, but everything I come up with isn't working. What I'm trying to accomplish is simple: I just want a popover to appear that describes what a button does when you hover over it. The button's code is as follows:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger deleteLine" type="button" id="deleteLine_<@=lineCount@>"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
```

I've tried a regex looking for a match at the front of the id:

```
$('[id^="deleteLine_"]').popover({ 
    trigger: "hover focus",
    content: "Delete this line."
});

$('button[id^="deleteLine_"]').popover({ 
    trigger: "hover focus",
    content: "Delete this line."
});
```

I've tried a regex on the id looking for a match anywhere in the id:

```
$('[id*="deleteLine_"]').popover({ 
    trigger: "hover focus",
    content: "Delete this line."
});

$('button[id*="deleteLine_"]').popover({ 
    trigger: "hover focus",
    content: "Delete this line."
});
```

And I've tried latching onto the class "deleteLine"

```
$('.deleteLine').popover({ 
    trigger: "hover focus",
    content: "Delete this line."
});
```

Struck out all three times. I'd like to avoid having to code "onmouseover" and "onfocus" attributes inline. I can't do static assignments (which works in other parts of the modal) due to the dynamic nature of the lines.

I'm using Bootstrap 2.3.2 and jQuery 2.1.1 in IE10 and FF21. Upgrading to newer versions isn't an option, unfortunately.

Comment: Why aren't you using the tooltip instead? That's what the tooltip is for anyway.

Comment: Someone client-side nixed the tooltips because they don't match the look of the popovers we have with information icons elsewhere.

Comment: You could try the technique in this solution for multiple trigger conditions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437818/twitter-bootstrap-popover-trigger-how-to-set-multiple-triggers

Comment: I put your code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2zkLs38/) and it works just fine.  Are you adding the popover to each line as it's added?

Comment: I'm not adding in each line, I'm trying to avoid it. What I want to do is say "Hey, there are multiple buttons like this on the modal, if the user hovers over any of them, make this popup appear"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<p title="this is title">What is this</div>
```

**JS**

```
  $(function() {
      $('[title]').attr("data-rel", "tooltip");
      $("[data-rel='tooltip']")
          .attr("data-placement", "top")
          .attr("data-content", function() {
              return $(this).attr("title")
          })
          .removeAttr('title');


      var showPopover = function() {
          $(this).popover('show');
      };
      var hidePopover = function() {
          $(this).popover('hide');
      };
      $("[data-rel='tooltip']").popover({
          trigger: 'manual'
      }).click(showPopover).hover(showPopover, hidePopover);

  });
```

Comment: Not a problem, sir :)