# Bootstrap Popover focus AND keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When using a Bootstrap popover for input error checking, I am trying to check the input on initial `focus` and on each subsequent `keyup`. For instance, here is the initial focus which works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){                      
$('.link input').popover({                       
  title:'Check for Caps:',
  trigger:'focus',
  placement:'right',
  html:'true',
  container:'body',
  content: function() {
     var content = $(this).val();
     var ok = '<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>';
     var notok = '<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>';
     var noCaps = content.search(/[A-Z]/) + 1 > 0 ? notok:ok;                       
     var msg = '<ul class="reqs"><li>'+ noCaps +' No Caps Please</li></ul>';
     return msg;
     }                                                  
   });  
});
```

However, where can I add a function that checks the input on subsequent keyups? Does it go outside or inside of this function?

This is not a duplicate of another post. [This Post just shows how to manually call the popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437818) which is already well documented in the bootstrap documentation. If that is all I needed, I would have just gotten it from the doc's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content of the popover only gets sets on initialization. The trigger only effects when the content will be shown it is not going to allow you to run the function each time the popover is shown.

You will need to initialize the popover. Then you will also need to run a function on keyup. Below example I changed noCaps to content just so you can get the idea that the event is firing and updating.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.link input').popover({
        title: 'Check for Caps:',
        trigger: 'focus',
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: 'true',
        container: 'body'
    }).on('keyup focus', function () {
        var element = $(this)
        var content = element.val();
        var ok = '<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>';
        var notok = '<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>';
        var noCaps = content.search(/[A-Z]/) + 1 > 0 ? notok : ok;
        var msg = '<ul class="reqs"><li>' + noCaps + ' No Caps Please</li></ul>';

        //This is the important stuff
        var popover = element.attr('data-content', msg).data('bs.popover');
        popover.setContent();
        popover.$tip.addClass(popover.options.placement);
    });
});
```

jsfiddle Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/uzLuzzuz/2/

I've also done something similar that is out on bootsnipp.com 
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/password-strength-popover

Comment: Thanks Sean. That doesn't seem to work. The text "No Caps Please" should be persistent as long as the input has focus and with each `keyup` we show either the `ok` variable or the `notok` variable which are just font awesome icons. Tried messing with your fiddle a little but I could not get it to work. It appears it is adding whatever is inside the input to the popover content on `keyup`.

Comment: Yeah i stated in the original response i changed the popup to use the content from the input box. I changed it back to use regular expression to check for capitals. See this link... http://jsfiddle.net/uzLuzzuz/1/

Comment: Hi Sean. Still fighting with this. The issue is that there is an initial value in the input at page load and it needs to be checked when the input comes into `focus`. In the example I gave, this works fine but the `keyup` checking does not. In your example the `keyup` checking works but the initial `focus` check doesn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change 'keyup' to 'keyup focus' see if that gives you the results you are looking for

Comment: Sorry that was sent from my phone last night incase you were under a deadline. See updated fiddle which fires the input value check upon focus and keyup http://jsfiddle.net/uzLuzzuz/2/